# how do i create a user account in unix using CLI?

Tags: linux, command-line

I am using Redhat and I want to make a user account using CLI. I am using this commands but I guess it's not working.

```
# useradd smithj -c 'John Smith' -m
# passwd smithj
```

and the result should be 
    Changing password for user smithj.
    New UNIX password:
    Retype new UNIX password:
    Passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.

Please shed some light on where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol #, as explained in another answer, represents the command line prompt. In this case # represents the root's command line prompt and $ represents the command line prompt for another user. So check you are executing those commands as root.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
useradd -c 'John Smith' -m smithj
```

according to man page for useradd

```
useradd [options] LOGIN
```

Comment: Yes, i did. It's not working.
Is "#" mandatory though?

Comment: The # represents the command line prompt, I believe, you don't actually type it.

Comment: # start a comment, you sould not type it. you must be root to create user. `id` should show you as root. (e.g. uid=0(root))